# Proper way of updating Google maps SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Recently I've updated Google maps SDK on my current project: I've noticed there are new feature like compasButton which is essential for my customers.
I've downloaded, removed and installed sdk again followed by [google instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)
Then I've made modification in app code, just added the line

```
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
```

and tried to build the app. The compiler says

> Property 'compassButton' not found on object of type 'GMSUISettings *'

I'm jumping to the GMSUISettings class declaration within xCode editor and see no compassButton property there. Although when I open the same header file with external editor I can see this property declared there. 
Maybe xCode has cached framework sources somehow, I've no idea how to make him change his mind. Does anyone have a clue?